# odoo 9 AssertionError assert self in records and field in fs

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9

while I am trying to update value that affect computed field I got this error:

> Odoo Server Error
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 647, in _handle_exception
>       return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 684, in dispatch
>       result = self._call_function(**self.params)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 320, in _call_function
>       return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
>       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 313, in checked_call
>       result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 963, in **call**
>       return self.method(*args, **kw)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 513, in response_wrap
>       response = f(*args, **kw)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 904, in call_kw
>       return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 896, in _call_kw
>       return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
>       return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 381, in old_api
>       result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 6036, in onchange
>       record.mapped(field_seq)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 5534, in mapped
>       recs = recs._mapped_func(operator.itemgetter(name))
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 5514, in _mapped_func
>       vals = [func(rec) for rec in self]
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 5752, in **getitem**
>       return self._fields[key].**get**(self, type(self))
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/fields.py", line 829, in **get**
>       self.determine_value(record)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/fields.py", line 927, in determine_value
>       record._prefetch_field(self)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
>       return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/abdalla/projects/greenway/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 3295, in _prefetch_field
>       assert self in records and field in fs
>   AssertionError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the problem:
the problem is that the method of the computed field is not exist (I renamed it accidentally). so when odoo try to get the value of this field it failed, and show this strange error